# PHP repeat function after 1 minute.

Tags: php, bots

I am running a function that gets user input and check db for the keyword. I want it to run like a bot program because others will be entering data to the db. I want it to do search every minute. like a bot program.

does this work?

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

if it does how can i limit to one Function and set 1 minute.

Comment: Set up a cron job on your server

Comment: What do you want to happen when your "bot" finds a keyword?

Comment: probably you have some miss-concepts: I am deducing you are making a sort of search/autocomplete. Do this on user side with javascript

Answer (score 3):

`set_time_limit(0)` only means that your script itself shouldn't time out if some task inside it is taking a long time. It doesn't loop anything. Also even if you run a cron task or shell script, you still need a way to send the results to the user every time the results change.

So if you want to update the user (or all current users) every time there are new results, without refreshing the page every time, your best bet is to use websockets.

Alternatively, use an AJAX call inside a `setInterval` function on client-side Javascript.